# Split and iterate over array and match a value

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to be able to filter products based on one of a, b, c, or d matching the value of `this.listFilter'

I think the code below is almost doing what I want, the split function returns an array but only seems to be matching on the first element in the array, I need to iterate over each element and check if it matches the value of `this.listFilter`.

The breadcrumb array contains:

`breadcrumb[
   'a > b > c > d'
]`

```
return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) => product.categories.category.breadcrumb[0].split(' > ').indexOf(this.listFilter));
```

Can anyone suggest a way to iterate over the array split by the " > " and check against the value of `this.listFilter`?

Comment: [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the index or `-1`, you'll have to add a check like `.indexOf(..) != -1` or `.indexOf(..) >= 0`

Comment: Or, replace `indexOf` with `includes`

Comment: Thank you very much, sincerely appreciated :)